# letter solicitation using a scanner and random variable

Tags: java, char, java.util.scanner

I am attempting to make a game where the user has to enter a letter to guess if that letter is within the word I have created. The word is:

final String thisWord = "awordwithmanyletters";
String guessWord = kb.?????

I am unsure how to go about this. I want to use the .contains() and .toLowerCase() in my variable, yet I have never learned this nor how to implement it. I am basically only curious how to implement this, the decision structure will be easy after this.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
final String thisWord = "awordwithmanyletters";
String guessLetter;
System.out.println("Enter guess one: ");
guessLetter = kb.nextLine();
if(thisWord.contains(guessLetter.toLowerCase())){
    System.out.println("success");
}
```

This check if the `guessWord`, in lower case, is within the `thisWord`.

```
final String thisWord = "awordwithmanyletters";
String guessWord = "wiTH";
if(thisWord.contains(guessWord.toLowerCase())){
    System.out.println("success");
}
```

Comment: I've added an edit as per your comment. You just do the same thing for guess #2 then.

Answer (score 0):

To get user input, you simply could use:

```
String guessWord = kb.next()
```

Then you can check if it is inside the string like:

```
thisWord.toLowerCase().contains( guessWord.toLowerCase() )
```

However, note that scanner's `next` returns the first consecutive string of characters from the input. If you want only one letter, or you need to make sure the user has input in your expected format, you need to validate the input before checking it is inside `thisWord`.